# split method not working in node js put operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, split

I'm providing an update action in my node js project.
I need to update it when data comes through the input, I am facing a problem like this.

If I send new data via input, the split method works.
But when I send the same data, the split method does not work. What can be the answer to this question? Can you help?

Data format sent;
`{ url: '/assets/images/upload/1678259610746.jpg' },{ url: '/assets/images/upload/1678259610749.jpg' }`

```
let imageData = req.body?.image.split(',');
const galleryCount = imageData.length;   
for (let i = 0; i < galleryCount; i++) {
  array.push(
    {
      url : imageData[i].split(' ')[2].replace(`'`,'').replace(`'`,''),
    }
  )
}
```

The function is as above if I enter a value in the input and send it, it works and I get the output as follows.

`/assets/images/upload/1678259610746.jpg /assets/images/upload/1678259610746.jpg`

But when I send the same data again, the function does not work, it gives an output like this.

`url: url: url:`

A very strange problem that I could not solve.

Comment: It seems like you got the incoming request body as a plain text and not as a parsed JS- Maybe you need to use form-data or JSON parser (depending on the request body format)?

Comment: What do you mean by "send the same data again"? Can you show request body for both times.

Comment: I mean the same data, I edit other inputs on this html form, but I do not edit the input with this json, then this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
let stringfyArray = [];
let dataArray = [];
let imageData = req.body?.image.split(',');

const galleryCount = imageData.length;

for (let i = 0; i < galleryCount; i++) {

  stringfyArray.push(
    {
      url : JSON.stringify(eval("(" + imageData[i] + ")")),
    }
  )
  dataArray.push(JSON.parse(stringfyArray[i].url))
  
}
```

This is how I solved the problem, maybe it can help other friends.